# SQL Delete with Inner Join ado.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

So I have two tables:

[image]

[image]

and I want to delete a record from `Kategoria-Adres`, where the `ID_Adres` in `Kategoria-Adres` is the same like `ID_Adres` in `Adres` when I select an item from a listbox.

```
 string delete_string1 = "DELETE FROM Kategoria-Adres INNER JOIN Adres ON
 Kategoria-Adres.ID_Adres = Adres.ID_Adres WHERE Adres.Adres LIKE "
 + listBox1_Selected_Item + " AND Adres.ID_Adres = Kategoria-Adres.ID_Adres";
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in your query.

Something like this should work:

```
DELETE FROM Kategoria-Adres
INNER JOIN [Adres] ON [Kategoria-Adres].[ID_Adres] = [Adres].[ID_Adres]
WHERE [Adres].[Adres] LIKE '%" + listbox1.SelectedValue + "%' AND [Adres].[ID_Adres] = [Kategoria-Adres].[ID_Adres]
```

As a side note, you should include your C# and ADO.Net code in the future incase you're missing something from there, and the error code.

Comment: I'm trying this, and that is a helpful answear, but the only thing now is that I get the error: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER' ". I'm checking this in sql server ofc.

Comment: Try removing the brackets I've included on the top line. I've edited answer to reflect this.

Comment: hmmm it worked when I did "DELETE k FROM Kategoria-Adres AS k". Have no idea why. Anyway thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your Like clause is missing the `%`

Comment: I'm looking at my code and I think I miss LIKE ' "   " ' now, but % ? I select item from a listbox and I put it into a string on select change event, so I have the string I want to use in the sql code and I delete the record in another table but with the same ID like the ID of the string's name.

Comment: put a breakpoint on this line of code and show us what it looks like after the string has been built.